# Vue 3 Composition API ref primitive property not reactive

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

So while building a tab system I'm taking advantage of useSlots and props in order to create an array of titles (these are the titles of every tab that I open in my tab system), then I create a ref property called **selectedTitle** in order to bind that title to a class and add css to highlight the tab selected by the user:

This is my component:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <ul
      class="tag-menu flex space-x-2"
      :class="defaultTagMenu ? 'default' : 'historic'"
      role="tablist"
      aria-label="Tabs Menu"
      v-if="tabTitles && tabTitles.length"
    >
      <li
        @click.stop.prevent="selectedTitle = title"
        v-for="title in tabTitles"
        :key="title"
        :title="title"
        role="presentation"
        :class="{ selected: title === selectedTitle }"
      >
        <a href="#" role="tab">
          {{ title }}
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <slot />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { ref, computed, useSlots, provide, watch } from "vue";
export default {
  props: {
    defaultTagMenu: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: true,
    },
  },
  setup() {
    const slots = useSlots();
    const tabTitles = computed(() =>
      slots.default()[0].children.map((tab) => tab.props.title)
    );
    const tabTitlesLength = computed(() => tabTitles.value.length);
    const selectedTitle = ref(tabTitles.value[0]);
    provide("selectedTitle", selectedTitle);
    provide("tabTitles", tabTitles);
    watch(
      () => tabTitlesLength,
      (newVal, oldVal) => {
        if (newVal < oldVal) {
          selectedTitle.value = ref(tabTitles.value[0]);
        }
      },
      {
        deep: true,
      }
    );
    return {
      tabTitles,
      selectedTitle,
      tabTitlesLength,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

This is the scenario: Whenever I close a tab (for the sake of this example that is working and not part of the problem) I want to close the tab and then what I expect is for the **selectedTitle** ref property of my component to be reactive, meaning to change it's value accordingly depending on the **tabTitles** array. When I inspect the component I see that every time I close a tab the **tabTitles** array change but not the **selectedTitle** value, is always the same value not matter what.

As you can see I'm trying to use a watcher in order to change the selected tab every time tabTitlesLength is less than it's older value (meaning a tab has been closed) but since I'm using deep:true the oldValue and the newValue are the same for the watcher

> Note: when mutating (rather than replacing) an Object or an Array and watch with deep option, the old value will be the same as new value because they reference the same Object/Array. Vue doesn't keep a copy of the pre-mutate value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally came up with something that worked based on @TymoteuszLao approach:

```
watch(tabTitlesLength, (currentValue, oldValue) => {
  console.log(currentValue, oldValue);
  if (currentValue < oldValue) {
    selectedTitle.value = tabTitles.value[0];
  }
});
```

Since I'm watching an array length there's no need to use deep:true. I have the old array length and the new value and can compare both values within my watcher.

Answer (score 0):

**Wrong**

Try to use [**reactive**](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html#reactive) instead of **ref**

```
import { reactive } from "vue";

const selectedTitle = reactive(tabTitles.value[0]);
```

**EDIT**

Try to make a *slots* reactive and then use the watcher on *tabTitles* to assign a new value to *selectedTitle*

```
const slots = useSlots();
const slotsReactive = ref(slots.default()[0].children);
const tabTitles = computed(() =>
  slotsReactive.value.map((tab) => tab.props.title)
);
const selectedTitle = ref(tabTitles.value[0]);
provide("selectedTitle", selectedTitle);
provide("tabTitles", tabTitles);
onMounted(() => {
  console.log("V3 mounted!");
});
watch(
  () => tabTitles,
  (newVal) => {
    selectedTitle.value = newVal.value[0];
  },
  {
    deep: true
  }
)
```

Comment: I have already tried that and I get a "value cannot be made reactive" error. I guess because the value is not an object, is a JS primitive.

Comment: Thanks @TymoteuszLao, unfortunately is not working. Neither the slotsReactive nor the tabTitles array gets updated when new tabs are added with your last approach (just FYI this was working as it was on my OQ). Just wondering if there are  new values to return with your approach that I'm not returning or there's a .value that has to be added somewhere.

Comment: Ok  @TymoteuszLao. I think I got it: There's not need to make the slots array reactive because it already is reactive and mutate in real time when I add or delete tabs. But that watcher really helped now is working BUT there's a caveat tho the watch function gets trigger every time something happen inside my tab component (eg. when I add a new message to the chat that is inside the tab) so when that happens the selectedTitle.value gets the newVal.value[0], which is not the way I want it to work. I guess I have to find a way for that watch just to be trigger when I finish a chat (close a tab).

Comment: @Lowtrux I am not sure if this will work but you can try to watch on tabTitles.value.length (or create a new computed property which will be the length of the tabTitles) and then if newVal < oldVal (in watcher) you will know that tab was deleted and you can reassign value to selectedTitle

Comment: Many thanks @TymoteuszLao. That's a great approach but there's a caveat tho. While testing I came to notice that when using deep:true in the watcher the oldvalue and the newvalue are always the same. This is a well know problem but I just can't a find a way around.  I have updated my code in the OQ.